# How to install mongo-hadoop for CDH4?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, jar

I want to use CDH 4.5 with mongo-hadoop:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop

When i execute:

./gradlew jar -Phadoop_version=CDH4

It fails and says its an "Unknown hadoop version". As far as I know CDH 4.5 uses Hadoop 2.0.0, but it does not show as an option in the documentation. It just says "The mongo-hadoop connector currently supports the following versions of hadoop: 0.23, 1.0, 1.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, and CDH 4 abd 5. If you would like to build against a specific version of Hadoop you simply need to pass -Phadoop_version= to gradlew when building."

What is the correct command to generate the jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cdh4 not CDH4.  I'll fix that in gradle, though.

Comment: Im assuming this works with cdh 4.0- cdh4.5? Even though it specifically is downloading CDH4.6?

Comment: Yes.  It should work just fine with it.  It used to compile against 4.3 but I bumped it a few weeks ago with no changes needed in code.

Comment: fwiw, i just pushed the change to gradle to normalize the version to lower case.